# Rust clippy check raise error `mutable_key_type` when use bytes as key's field

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The following code：

```rust
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Id {
    value: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Id2 {
    value: Bytes,
}

pub struct IdSet {
    pub set: HashSet<Id>,
}

impl IdSet {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, id: Id) {
        self.set.insert(id);
    }

    pub fn insert_all(&mut self, ids: HashSet<Id>) {
        self.set.extend(ids);
    }
}

pub struct IdSet2 {
    pub set: HashSet<Id2>,
}

impl IdSet2 {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, id: Id2) {
        self.set.insert(id);
    }

    pub fn insert_all(&mut self, ids: HashSet<Id2>) {
        self.set.extend(ids);
    }
}
```

cargo clippy raise an error:

```
   Checking playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: mutable key type
  --> src/lib.rs:37:39
   |
37 |     pub fn insert_all(&mut self, ids: HashSet<Id2>) {
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[deny(clippy::mutable_key_type)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#mutable_key_type
```

`HashSet<Id>` as param is alright, but `HashSet<Id2>` as param is an error, Why?

This is rust playground URL: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36529bbb847be2342e6e4ef8a44d4fe9

Comment: Well, if you follow the link by clippy, it says that it is an error by default if a map/set has mutable key types, one major example being `bytes::Bytes`. That's exactly where the difference between your `HashSet<Id>` and `HashSet<Id2>` is.

Comment: To be clear, here mutability refers to interior mutability.

Comment: @edwardw what is the main difference between Bytes and Vec<u8> at here?